# What is Item index after destructring scoped slot in Vuetify Data Iterator?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

To cope with nested object I had to destruct the scoped slot in v-data-iterator as **hb**

```
<v-data-iterator :items="persons" content-tag="v-layout" row="row" wrap="wrap">
    <v-flex slot="item" slot-scope="{item:{hobbies:hb}}" xs12="xs12" sm6="sm6" md4="md4" lg3="lg3">
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
                <h4>{{ hb.name }}</h4>
                <v-btn color="error" @click="removeHoppy(hg.index)" block="block" flat="flat">
                    <v-icon left="left">delete</v-icon>Remove</v-btn>
            </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
    </v-flex>
</v-data-iterator>
```

Now I want to remove the item from `person` but I don't have the index as **hb.index** is undefined.

Is there a way to have index if we manipulate the **props** as in my case using Vuetify Data Iterator (may this could be applied to other Vuetify components as well)?

Comment: You have a typo, you wrote `hg.index` instead of `hb.index`. (Anyways, it won't work)

Answer (score 0):

`index` is passed outside each item object.

To get the `index` of each items, do this

```vuejs
    <v-flex 
        slot="item" 
        slot-scope="{item:{hobbies:hb},index}" 
        xs12="xs12"
        sm6="sm6"
        md4="md4"
        lg3="lg3"
    >
    </v-flex>
```

Comment: The index returns actual item id, not current item index in v-iterator id. Looks like I have lost track of array.